# Decode a password before login Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a login form with spring security jdbc authentication, it works well with normal form submission.

Now i've encrypted the user password on client side with javascript, i use `cryptoJs` and the encrypted password is submitted to the server, the problem is that i have to decode the password before let spring check the password hash in the database and i can't figure how to do that, i've tried with a custom filter

```
public class LoginFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{

    public LoginFilter(AuthenticationManager auth){
        super.setAuthenticationManager(auth);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException{
        //Decode password
        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    } 

}
```

it intercept the request, i can get the password and decode it but i can't pass to the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, how can i pass to spring the decoded password instead of the encoded submitted by the user?
P.S. I'm not using Https and i know that javascript encryption is probably useless

Comment: I'd like to help, but I need more information. Can you post the contents of your spring security configuration class (i.e.: the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and is annotated with @EnableWebSecurity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, not sure if it is the best possible but it works, Spring uses a `PasswordEncoder` object to check that the password typed by the user match the stored (and hashed) password.

I was using a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` which uses the method `matches(rawPass,encodedPass)` to check the password, so i've created my own `PasswordEncoder` in this way

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
    .usersByUsernameQuery(USER_QUERY)
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLE_QUERY)
    .dataSource(dataSource)
    .passwordEncoder(new PasswordEncoder(){

        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {

            // Decoding stuff on the encrypted password sended by the client (rawPassword)

            return encoder.matches(decryptedPassword, encodedPassword);
        }

        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
            //Same crypto operation to get the plain password
            return encoder.encode(decryptedPassword);
        }
    });
}
```

so the client send the encrypted password to the server, the custom `PasswordEncoder` decrypt it to get back the plain password then pass it to the `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, Spring security will handle the rest of the authentication process

Comment: As per my knowledge Its not possible to decrypt an encrypted password using BCryptPasswordEncoder , can u explain how did u done this decryption and then pass it to spring for encryption..Plss..

Comment: I didn't do that, the password was firstly encrypted using other  Javascript libraries then sended to the server, so i needed to decrypt it with some Java libraries and then pass the raw password resulting to the BCrypt and let him work as always

Comment: There is difference b/w encryption and hashing. Hashing is one way i.e. once hashed you can't get the value back, whereas, in encryption you have key which helps you to recover original data i.e. decryption. BCryptPasswordEncoder provides hashing function hence you can't get back original value.

Comment: I didn't need to get back from hashing, i had to decrypt a string to get the plain password and then check its hash stored on the db.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, ideologically it's really understandable - if you receive an encrypted password, so you can get and store a password hash, and later check it (I think no one framework stores and compares real passwords, just their hashes). But this is your own problem and you will solve it from your side ...

Really, you cannot set request parameters anywhere, but you can set a new request attribute and anywhere to get it from request: `request.setAttribute("<string key>", <object value>);` and `var value = (String) request.getAttribute("<string key>");`

Comment: yes i've undestand that, so how can i extract the password from the request, decode it, and tell to spring to check the hash of the decoded password?

Comment: You don't need to do that. Look how Spring validates passwords, and send from a client the password hash, not a pure password. If you use really secured algorithms like shaXXX (not md5) you can send them from a client without SSL.